# Is it possible to calculate the variation of magnetization M(T) for a diluted magnetic semiconductor?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, magnetism, physical-properties-of-materials

Is there any simulation program (for example a DFT package) to determine the variation of magnetization M(T) for [dilute magnetic semiconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_semiconductor) or doped semiconductors with different concentrations of dopants?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: +1. I made an edit to specify what I think you meant by "different concentrations", so please re-edit if I made a mistake. Also, you say "dilute magnetic semiconductor ***or*** doped semiconductor with different concentrations": Dilute semiconductors are already doped, but doped semiconductors are not necessarily magnetic semiconductors. Is it right that you want to be able to calculate M(T) for either dilute magnetic semiconductors regardless of whether the concentrations are different/same, ***or*** doped semiconductors with different concentrations of dopants but regardless of magnetism?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or anyone else wants to give an answer.